# How do I make a PHP variable value visible to a PHP Class in another file?

Tags: php

How do I make the variable item from one PHP file visible to a PHP class that is a different file?

The variable:

```
$item = "item";
```

The class:

```
class Item{
  public function getItem(){
     $result = $item + 5;
     echo $result;
  }
}
```

Comment: Put `global $item;` in the function. It doesn't matter if they're in the same or different files.